# Magic trackpad natural scrolling interruption

Tags: xorg, scrolling

I have my Apple Magic Trackpad connected to my Ubuntu 12.04 distro and it's working great with a custom xorg configuration file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-apple-wireless-trackpad.conf`:

```
# Configuration for fine-tuning only the Apple Magic Trackpad.
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Apple Magic Trackpad"
    Driver "synaptics"

    # Match only the Apple Magic Trackpad
    MatchUSBID "05ac:030e"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"

    # Set resolution tweaks for better response
    Option "VertResolution" "75"
    Option "HorizResolution" "75"

    # Set a timeout for multi finger click so accidental double-clicks don't
    # happen when right clicking and other gestures
    Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "100"

    # Increase sensitivity
    Option "MinSpeed" "1.75"
    Option "MaxSpeed" "1.85"
    Option "AccelFactor" "0.05"

    # Scrolling   
    Option "VertScrollDelta" "-100"
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-100"
EndSection
```

The negative scroll delta gives me "natural scrolling," ie reverse scrolling. The problem I'm having is that as I scroll, it will often "jump."

This is what happens:

1. I two-finger drag to scroll down or up to a certain point.
2. I then do the same action again quickly to continue scrolling
3. The content jumps in the opposite direction of which I'm scrolling.

I've done a [screen capture](https://vimeo.com/68968395) here. Watch it in full screen and pay attention to the scroll bar at left.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your "quick" scrolling is exceeding the scroll delta.

At any rate, I also have a Magic Trackpad on Ubuntu 12. I simply swapped the ZAxisMapping buttons to get natural scrolling.

Detailed instructions [on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations).

TL;DR:

Use `xev` to find the "swipe up" and "swipe down" buttons for your trackpad. Put them in reverse order in `xorg.conf`.